# Yahoo OAuth2 not work

Tags: angular, oauth, yahoo

I have a problem with Yahoo Oauth2 in angular 2! Everything works until the `get_token!` call, but when I call `get_token` as service, Yahoo returns: `Error 500 with No Access-Control-Allow-Origin!`.

How can solved this problem?

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this._activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((param: Params) => {
        let code = param['code'];
        let token_id = param['id_token']
        this._yahooService.callYahoo(code)
            .subscribe(res => {
                console.log(res)
            });
    });
}
```

.

```
callYahoo(code: any, token_id?: any): Observable<Object> {
    let yahooAddress: string = 'https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/get_token';
    let _url = new URLSearchParams();
    let header = new Headers();

    header.append('client_id', 'xxx');
    header.append('client_secret', 'xxx');
    header.append('grant_type', 'authorization_code');
    header.append('redirect_uri', 'http://example.com/call-back');
    header.append('code', code);
    let body: string = _url.toString();

    header.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    header.append('Authorization', 'Basic xxx');


    return this._http.post(yahooAddress, body, { headers: header })
        .map(res => {
            return res
        })
}
```

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing client_id, client_secret, etc, as headers, they must be passed as properties of a JSON object in the POST request body.

You only need one header, Authorization.  Everything else goes in the body.

Yahoo has a good web page showing exactly how to create the get_token request.
https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/openid_connect/getting_started.html